# In R, how do you evaluate ... in the calling function?

Tags: r, environment, callstack

If I want to know what is stored in a `...` argument within an R function, I can simply convert it to be a list, like so

```
foo <- function(...)
{
  dots <- list(...)
  print(dots)
}

foo(x = 1, 2, "three")
#$x
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "three"
```

What I can't figure out is how to evaluate `...` in the calling function.  In this next example I want the contents of `baz` to return the `...` argument to `bar`.

```
bar <- function(...)
{
  baz()
}

baz <- function()
{ 
  # What should dots be assigned as?
  # I tried                                           
  # dots <- get("...", envir = parent.frame())
  # and variations of
  # dots <- eval(list(...), envir = parent.frame())
  print(dots)
}

bar(x = 1, 2, "three")
```

`get("...", envir = parent.frame())` returns `<...>`, which looks promising, but I can't figure out how to extract anything useful from it.

`eval(list(...), envir = parent.frame())` throws an error, claiming that `...` is used incorrectly.

How can I retrieve the `...` from `bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed a combination of `eval` and `substitute`.  `baz` should be defined as

```
baz <- function()
{ 
  dots <- eval(substitute(list(...), env = parent.frame()))
  print(dots)
}
```

Comment: +1 This is an interesting example.  If you have a chance, it would be nice if you could update this with an explanation for *why* this might be necessary for the ellipsis, but not for other variables?

Comment: @Shane: A good question.  I'm going to dig around further, but this is rapidly getting into brain-melting territory.  To be continued...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
bar <- function(...)
{
  baz(...=...)
}

baz <- function(...)
{ 
  print(list(...))
}

bar(x = 1, 2, "three")
```

Just assign it in the subfunction.

Alternatively, you can assign the ellipsis as a list in the parent function:

```
bar <- function(...)
{
  bar.x <- list(...)
  baz()
}

baz <- function()
{ 
  dots <- get("bar.x", envir = parent.frame())
  print(dots)
}

bar(x = 1, 2, "three")
```

This is the same idea, but I wouldn't suggest it because you're overwriting the ellipsis:

```
bar <- function(...)
{
  ... <- list(...)
  baz()
}

baz <- function()
{ 
  dots <- get("...", envir = parent.frame())
  print(dots)
}

bar(x = 1, 2, "three")
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I can't/don't want to modify `baz`?  Is evaluating `...` in a different environment possible?

Comment: See my second solution?  I'm not sure about that <...> object; it's class is "..." and it clearly isn't the same as the original ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: don't.  Trying to redefine R's scoping rules is only likely to end up in heartache and pain.

Comment: a locale-specific exhalation comes to mind (buffered since comments have a min length): Rmen